# I am starting to code but I don't how why my variables are never defined despite I do it

Tags: javascript, variables

For example, I define a variable with an integer and if I try to check the variable in the console it says "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about JavaScript. The reason you see it's `undefined` because: "This usually occurs when a variable is declared. Here the variable is assigned a memory or space by the JavaScript engine. Because of this, once a variable is declared, it takes a value of undefined even before assignment."
When you assign a value (even null) to the created variable, it will no longer be `undefined` anymore
https://scotch.io/courses/10-need-to-know-javascript-concepts/declaring-javascript-variables-var-let-and-const

Answer (score -1):

Try assigning the value to variable when you define it.

Eg: int a=1;

Answer (score -1):

in your console type let a = 5;
then type a.

your output will be 5. Why? because you instantiated the variable but never call it afterwards.